# Crystal Reports can access tables, but not views

Tags: sql-server, permissions, crystal-reports

I've written a Crystal report that primarily works from a temporarily MDB file that is created on the fly in an Application (which I do not have access to source code for).

I need additional data, so I linked to a secondary MSSQL database where I store more information.

I was able to add tables from this SQL database to my report, and link to them with no trouble.  But when I try to include views in this same SQL database in this report, I get a "Logon Error".

My first thought was that is is a permission issue, but I haven't set permissions for specific tables and views in this database, only permissions to the entire database.

Frustratingly, I don't see any errors in the SQL logs for the database.

Does anyone have ideas on what I can check to get this fixed?

Just To Clarify: I can see these views in the Crystal Report, and I can add them, add fields to the report, and create links.  I can even Browse Data in fields within the view in Crystal.  It's only when running these reports from the 3rd party application that I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Is SQL Server set to use NT Authentication? If so, the 3rd-party application is probably running under a user context that doesn't have permissions.

Comment: It is set to use NT Authentication. Would that cause the application to be unable to access tables within my secondary database, but not views?  If so, would Crystal reports be able to run a stored procedure to add all records from a view to a table as a work-around?  Thank you for your thoughts and time!

Comment: NT Authentication means authentication based on the WINDOWS user account under which the process is running. So you need to add the account under which the app is running to the SQL Server permissions.
Or change from NT Auth to SQL Server auth.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  I'll try it and report back.